# Error occur while sending date fields to server in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using react to send date to server but there is an error

{message: 'Invalid date format. Date should be in the format YYYY-MM-DD.', field: 'from'}

I'm completely sure the data is valid and here is the code

```
   const handleFilter = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(fromDate);
    console.log(toDate);
    try {
      const date = {
        from: dayjs(fromDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        to: dayjs(toDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      };
      console.log(date);
      const res = await newRequest.get("/analysis", date);
      console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

and there is the console

[image]

I'm tried a lot of answers like
JSON.stringify(date);
before sending
nothing work !!!

there is the postman and it's work fine in postman
[image]

Comment: We can't send body in `get` request. It should be changed to `post `.Please let me know if it works for  you.

Comment: @Jagroop
I uploaded the postman request

Answer (score 0):

The params you're sending through the GET request by Postman are called "body" in the Postman nav bar. But doing a GET request, you could'nt use "body" like you usually do when you're doing a POST request.

When you're doing a GET request you should to pass the params instead body whitin the second param of "newRequest.get" method.
Wich will be on the request query params:

```
"https://resturant.asusapps.com/api/v1/analysis?from=2024-02-01&to=2024-03-30"
```

Then, once "newRequest" is an Axios instance, you should do like this:

```
const res = await newRequest.get("/analysis", {
    params: {
        from: date.from,
        to: date.to
    }
});
```

Your code will be like this:

```
const handleFilter = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(fromDate);
    console.log(toDate);

    try {
        const date = {
            from: dayjs(fromDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            to: dayjs(toDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        };

        console.log(date);
        const res = await newRequest.get("/analysis", {
            params: {...date} 
        });
        console.log(res);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Hope this helps